# Creating multiple objects in one shot within ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I know that in Author & Deploy draft we can create objects one by one, like data sets, linked service, pipelines etc. But what if you have all those JSONs stored in a single file, why can't you just copy and paste it all to draft and deploy them all in one shot? I know there will be dependency of objects on one another, but that ADF should be able to determine. As of now, copying individual objects one by one and deploying individually is a pain. I know there are programmatic ways to do it easily. But I am specifically asking about Author & Deploy feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume the biggest reason they do not handle this is as you mention the dependency checking they would have to perform.

An alternative idea, if you use visual studio you can download [Microsoft Azure DataFactory Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/371a4cf9-0093-40fa-b7dd-be3c74f49005), another [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-data-factory-visual-studio-extension-for-authoring-pipelines/).  This will give you a DataFactory project template inside visual studio.  You can then store all of your JSON files in the Data Factory project and then "Publish" the project to a DataFactory in azure from visual studio.  You also get the benefit of being able to check in the files into source control.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, yes, but then as I said it is one of the programmatic ways. I wanted to know if there is a way to do it in 'one shot' in Author & Deploy -- so yes I got my answer that it is not possible. Thanks